# Strange AUI behaviour

Tags: liferay-aui

Up until now i assumed a call to AUI would be processed synchronously within the embedding JavaScript. Now I noticed the following behaviour:

```
    Liferay.on('allPortletsReady',
        function() {
           AUI().use('node', function(A) {
                // (1) --> set some global var here
           });
           // (2) --> use global var here
        }
    );
```

I expected the execution order
(1)
(2)

I got
(2)
(2)
(2)
(1)
(1)
(1)

I could live with the triple execution but I can't explain the reverse order.

The problem was easily solved by moving (2) inside the AUI sandbox, but I still wonder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `.use()` is called asynchronously. When calling `AUI().use('node', function(A) {...});`, the node-module has to be loaded and attached before the the function inside (`function(A) {...}`) is called.

So what is happening is that while the node-module is being loaded, the code lines after `use()` are being called, and when the module has been successfully loaded and attached, the function (`function(A) {...}`) is called.

See the documentation on `.use()` here: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/yui/#understanding-yuiuse

(AUI is an extension of YUI)

This might also be helpful: [Getting started with YUI3 and AlloyUI](http://www.slideshare.net/zenorocha/getting-started-with-yui3-and-alloyui)